# What is happening inside a jar if it is loaded by maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, startup

I am currently working on a Maven dependency. And now I have the question, what happens when the person who includes the dependency (aka my jar) in his project (via Maven)
Because my dependency/project relies on data that is in the property file. And I need to load them before you can use the project and actually load them into static attribute fields of classes.

Comment: You are loading property content into static field attributes? Really. Why not defining that directly as constants within the class itself... also you can load properties via the classpath from your own class.. ???

Comment: For the reason that they can change and you don't always want to/can't change the code. Because it is used as a Maven dependency. Ergo those people who use it can't change the code.

Comment: If you need to change the code based on that ...there might be some design issues. Furthermore you can define a property in your dependency and your classes can load that if you do it correctly... Can you show how it is done?